# google geolocation api key is getting rejected when api key is valid? i'm using python and tkinter

Tags: python, geolocation, api-key, google-api-key-restrictions

After successfully verifying my API key on Google Console and ensuring that everything was in order, I encountered a persistent issue when running my program. Despite my efforts, I consistently received an error message that prevented the program from executing as expected.

```
{'error': {'code': 400, 'message': 'API key not valid. Please pass a valid API key.', 'errors': [{'message': 'API key not valid. Please pass a valid API key.', 'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'badRequest'}], 'status': 'INVALID_ARGUMENT', 'details': [{'@type': 'type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo', 'reason': 'API_KEY_INVALID', 'domain': 'googleapis.com', 'metadata': {'service': 'geolocation.googleapis.com'}}]}}
```

and i don't know what it means

this is my code
https://pastebin.com/Fyb98MWv

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.